# How to locate kendo button by class using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, kendo-ui

I am trying to locate and click a button using Selenium in python. The webpage is kendo based and here is the relevant code for the button:

```
<div class="k-header k-grid-toolbar k-grid-top">
   <button class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-excel" type="button">
```

I have tried using this python code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-excel").click()
```

It raises an exception:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".k-grid-excel"}
```

Can anyone advise on a better method to find the button?

Comment: Have you tried with css selector? driver.find_element_by_css_selector(.k-button.k-button-icontext.k-grid-excel)

Comment: @IwonaAndrejewicz Thank you, I just tried that and it worked. I had to add a wait in there as well since it goes through a login page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the CSS Selector to find it and I had to put a wait in there as well:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 15)

element = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#grid > div.k-header.k-grid-toolbar.k-grid-top '
                                                                      '> button')))
element.click()
```